# How to create ami instance programmatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

lately I am doing some POC's in amazon elastic cloud. I created a sample instance and I uploaded my sample web application and finally saw my hello world jsp.

Now I am trying to create one more instance and want to send data from my first instance to second instance. I know that this can be achieved  through zookeeper. But I want to create my second instance programmatically and not through the management console.

How to achieve this?
I am thinking that this has something to do with the amazon s3 where we bundle our ami. But not sure about it. Can anyone give me guidelines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is a link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130119043746/http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonEC2/dg/2006-06-26/creating-an-ami.html) to the Amazon documentation for creating an AMI. Amazon provide a set of [command line tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351) so you should be able to call these from your script.

you may also find these 3rd party [scripts](https://gist.github.com/249915) useful for creating a bootable EBS from a running instance.

Or it may be more useful to invoke the [AWS EC2 APIs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/) more directly from your application.

Comment: you're welcome, in fact all the commands in the web interface are also doable using the ec2 command line tool set.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [Packer](https://www.packer.io/intro/why/) from Hashicorp to automate the creation of amazon AMIs. 
Check out the link below to find out how to create an AMI using packer :

https://www.packer.io/intro/getting-started/build-image/